# mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 8`

Tags: mono

I am in the process of *trying* to get my mono website to run on Apache.  I've gone through various tutorials on the installation and testing, and while I can get mono to run through xsp from the development server, Apache simply won't work.

I receive, `mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 8`

I've tried installing mono probably 4 or 5 times through different tutorials, so I don't know where I've gone wrong.  There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of help for this issue anywhere -- as I've searched pretty deeply.

When I run the command sudo apt-get install mono-xsp2, I receive `mono-xsp2 is already the newest version`.  The same goes for mono-server-2.  I receive `mono-apache2-server is already the newest version`.

The complete error is

> System.InvalidOperationException: mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 8
>     at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoRequest.GetInitialData () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoRequest..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.Socket client) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.WebServer.RequestReader..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.Socket client) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [Tue May 03 09:51:35 2011] [error] (104)Connection reset by peer: read_data failed
>   [Tue May 03 09:51:35 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered.  This will be closed.  If this question is still valid, please add more detail and flag for it to be reopened.